# What after git full reset and pull, server has different on branch in rep?

Tags: git

I clear git branch and reload again.
I do:

- `git reset --hard HEAD^`
- `git checkout master`
- `git pull origin master`

After which git says: Already up-to-date.
However, in the server is the work old code.
I do a fetch, but it does not work; I do a clean, it does not work; I do a reset as the first action in reflog, and upload all changes, but again, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the git remote is properly set

```
git remote -v
```

This should give you links for `fetch` and `push` check if they are working. Usually both links are same.

To test if they are working. Try creating a new branch in local. Commit something there and push it to github. And from github.com see if the branch is present there.

After that try these:

```
git reset --hard
git clean -fd
git fetch
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

If this dont work, just delete the folder and clone it again.